# Match pairs in a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, select

I don't know of the title is any good, but I'm trying to figure out a SELECT statement for a MySQL database that gives me matching items. I have two tables.

Example:

```
Offers
------
FK_User_ID | FK_Skill_ID | (other columns that are not relevant)
1            1
2            2

Requests
--------
FK_User_iD | FK_Skill_ID | (other columns that are not relevant)
1          | 2
2          | 1
```

You see what I mean? User 1 has skill 1 and seeks skill 2 -- User 2 has skill 2 and seeks skill 1. We have a match!

Say I'm user 1. How can I get the users and skills that have a Offer/Request match with me?

As user 1, I would like to retrieve the following data:

```
FK_User_ID | FK_Skill_ID | Type
2            1             Request
2            2             Offer
```

I hope my problem is clear. Any help is greatly appreciated.

More details: A user can have more than one skill and can request more than one skill. A match does not mean every skill needs to be matched, but at least one. And I would like to know *which* one then. It's only about skills that match.

Comment: Can you be a little more precise? Can a user have more than one skill? Can a user request more than one skill? Does a match mean the user matches all the requested skills? Can a matching user have other skills not listed in the request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT FK_User_ID, FK_Skill_ID, 'Offer' AS Type FROM offers WHERE FK_Skill_ID IN (SELECT FK_Skill_ID FROM requests WHERE FK_User_ID = 1)
UNION
SELECT FK_User_ID, FK_Skill_ID, 'Request' AS Type FROM requests WHERE FK_Skill_ID IN (SELECT FK_Skill_ID FROM offers WHERE FK_User_ID = 1)
```

This query will return a list of requests/offers for user with ID 1. It will return all the offers user 1 has requests for and all requests user 1 has offers for. If you can update question with more details about your data, as @Chris suggested then I might be of more help.

UPDATE:

If you need a match on both request and offer then it will be a bit more work.

```
SELECT matching_offers.*, 'Offer' as type FROM 
(SELECT FK_User_ID, FK_Skill_ID FROM offers WHERE FK_Skill_ID IN (SELECT FK_Skill_ID FROM requests WHERE FK_User_ID = 1)) AS matching_offers INNER JOIN
    (SELECT FK_User_ID, FK_Skill_ID FROM requests WHERE FK_Skill_ID IN (SELECT FK_Skill_ID FROM offers WHERE FK_User_ID = 1)) matching_requests ON matching_offers.FK_User_ID=matching_requests.FK_User_ID
UNION
SELECT matching_requests.*, 'Request' as type FROM 
(SELECT FK_User_ID, FK_Skill_ID FROM offers WHERE FK_Skill_ID IN (SELECT FK_Skill_ID FROM requests WHERE FK_User_ID = 1)) AS matching_offers INNER JOIN
    (SELECT FK_User_ID, FK_Skill_ID FROM requests WHERE FK_Skill_ID IN (SELECT FK_Skill_ID FROM offers WHERE FK_User_ID = 1)) matching_requests ON matching_offers.FK_User_ID=matching_requests.FK_User_ID
```

This will be very unefficient but should work. Maybe someone whos SQLfu is better than mine can improve it)

Answer (score 0):

Start with a query like this, which returns every possible combination of rows from the two tables where the skill matches:

```
SELECT offers.FK_User_ID as offering, offers.FK_Skill_ID as skill, requests.FK_User_ID as requesting
FROM offers, requests
WHERE offers.FK_Skill_ID = requests.FK_Skill_ID
```

To find users and skills that match 'your' offer, select from this where `offering` is 'you'. To find users and skills that match 'your' request, select from this where `requesting` is 'you'.