# Matched pairs with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a problem similar to this one --> [Match pairs in a MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026049/match-pairs-in-a-mysql-database), but still a little different.

Consider two groups of students, freshmen and all other students of a high school (sophomores, juniors and seniors). You would like to match the arriving freshmen with more experienced students as buddies. All students have filled out a questionnaire that comes up with a score that you would like to use as matching criterion. Scores of matched pairs may differ up to 10 percent, but should be as close as possible. At the end, there may be freshmen without a buddy if scores simply don't match, and as there are more non-freshmen than freshmen, not every student will be matched, of course.

Your source table looks like this:

```
  Student ID | Group        | Score
    1        | Freshman     | 10
    2        | Freshman     | 15
    3        | Non-Freshman | 11
    4        | Non-Freshman | 16
    5        | Non-Freshman | 30
    ...
```

In this case, `1+3` and `2+4` would be match. A perfect output would like this:

```
 Student ID    | Group        | Score | Matched Pair ID
     1         | Freshman     | 10    | 1
     3         | Non-Freshman | 11    | 1
     2         | Freshman     | 15    | 2
     4         | Non-Freshman | 16    | 2
```

Two characteristics of the given scenario make the problem tricky:

1. Every freshman shall be matched to only one other (**non-freshman**) student even if there is more than one possible combination.
2. Once a buddy pair match has been created, these students are no longer available for other matches.

In the meantime, I solved my problem with a php script, but there has to be a way to do it with mysql.

When I try...

```
select a.id, a.score, b.id, b.score from table t1 
join table t2 on t1.score between t2.score*0.9 and t2.score*1.1 and t1.id<>t2.id
group by a.id;
```

... the same student from table t2 may be matched multiple times. However, every student may only have one partner. Secondly, a random match is selected. What I want is a match with the least possible difference in scores.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Your two "characteristics" seem redundant. What's the difference between the two?

Comment: Correct, I just specified the thwo characteristics for sake of clarity

Comment: @X.L.Ant+Goodmood: I tried to join sub-queries, one having the freshmen, one having the other students. However, I can't think of a way to mark a student as already matched so that he doesn't get matched again